# Triggering ToolTip Through button rather than dynamic appearance

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to have Validation errors for my RadMaskedTextBox, Currently I was able to do that but it's dynamic and I want to change that.

If I set the range only < 250, and I put 500 inside the textbox it'll trigger and the Validation Error will appear.

What I want to happen is the Validation Error only happen when my button is pressed. May I ask how do I convert to do that?

Xaml

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="Red">Error!</TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<controls:RadMaskedCurrencyInput 
    x:Name="radMaskedCurrencyInput"
    InputBehavior="Insert"
    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate }"
                              Value="{Binding Path=DecimalValue,
                              ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                              ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
                              NotifyOnValidationError=false,
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<Button Content="Execute"  cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [ExecuteMessage]"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private decimal decimalValue;

public decimal DecimalValue
{
    get { return decimalValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value > 250)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Value cannot be greater than 250.");
        }
        else
            decimalValue = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("DecimalValue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If code-behind is acceptable:

Set `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`, and then when the button is clicked:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BindingExpression be = radMaskedCurrencyInput.GetBindingExpression(RadMaskedCurrencyInput.ValueProperty);
    be.UpdateSource();
}
```

See MSDN [UpdateSourceTrigger Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When you set the UpdateSourceTrigger value to Explicit, the source value only changes when the application calls the UpdateSource method.